# Integer division in JavaScript Error

Tags: javascript, math

When i try to divide and get a result using the following equation in `Javascript`

```
var level = (userLevel + 1)/2;
```

where userLevel = 7

i get `35.5` as a result instead of 4 ?

what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: All JavaScript numeric values are floating point.

Answer (score 4):

userLevel is a string, use

```
var level = (parseInt(userLevel) + 1)/2;
```

7+1 evaluates to 71 as 7 is a string

Answer (score 0):

javascript will consider your userLevel as a sttring for that you have convert the type into int or parse it to int

Try this :

```
var level = ((userLevel-0) + 1)/2;
```

Cheers :-)